# How to skip and sort by alphabet string array read in line by line

Tags: java

I'm reading in a file line by line and I need sort lines alphabetically, for example, in the below example, it should sort by first letter of each word and output it. I'm stuck on how to sort it by first character of each word alphabetically and retain the numbers in front of each word. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
output: 567 cat
        123 dog

FILE2 = "123 dog\n567 cat\n";

String args[] = {"-a", "5", inputFile.getPath()};

String expected = 567 cat
                  123 dog
```

I've tried reading in the lines and sorting but it sorts based on the numbers first.

```
if (arguments.equals("-a")) {                      
   List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines((Paths.get(filename)));

    List<String> matchedLines = lines.stream().sorted()
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It depends on what you mean with “word” in your example. If I were you I would create a new Comparator<String> implementation, overriding the compare method. Now you should retrieve first char of the two words, cast it as int and manage the consequent “compare” output depending on the relation between two integers. For example: first letter is converted to int and is 25, the second one is 54. Return 1 means that first word comes first than the second one, and so on. From that you can use Collections.sort(listOfStrings, new CustomComparator) and you’re done :)

Comment: I hope you catch my idea :)

Comment: Take a look at my code and see if it suits your need. If yes, accept it. @VuDang

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like following( take a note I didn't put anything in file, you could get string out of file easily as you already did ). Following code assumes you have got string from your file:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //what we have got from file
    String text = "123 dog\n567 cat\n";
    //split text to substrings by new line
    String[] splitted = text.split("\n");
    // create treemap and sort it from greatest to lowest number
    Map<Integer, String> mapOfStrings = new TreeMap<Integer, String>().descendingMap();
    //put all substrings into our map, following assumes a form that first substring is a text and second substring is an integer
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
        mapOfStrings.put(Integer.valueOf(splitted[i].substring(0, splitted[i].indexOf(" "))), splitted[i].substring(splitted[i].indexOf(" "), splitted[i].length()));
    }
   //iterate thru map, for each entry in it print its key and value in single line
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : mapOfStrings.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

If you would like to sort by letters( from a to z ) following code would suffice:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "123 dog\n567 cat\n4 zebra\n1983 tiger\n1 lion\n383 turtle";
        String[] splitted = text.split("\n");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splitted));
        Map<String, Integer> mapOfStrings = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            mapOfStrings.put(splitted[i].substring(splitted[i].indexOf(" "), splitted[i].length()),Integer.valueOf(splitted[i].substring(0, splitted[i].indexOf(" "))));

        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : mapOfStrings.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue()+ " " + entry.getKey());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it out!

Comment: this works great for this sample file.  For the .descendingMap(), when I add 4 zebra to file, it will output 567 cat, 4 zebra, 123 dog. It sorts descending based on numbers instead of the phrases cat, dog , zebra. Thank you!

Comment: @VuDang If you would like to sort it from a to z, I have made a little update to the code. Hope this will serve you good. If it is smt you were looking for, make sure to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi @MS90, it's sorting a-z but now shows number trailing , i.e "dog 1", number needs to prepend the string , i.e. "1 dog". Thanks!

Comment: Great! Oh I forgot to switch keys and values, I have changed in for loop System.out.println(entry.getValue()+ " " + entry.getKey()); Copy and paste now a code from Update 2 and see if it suits your needs. @VuDang